# Un "compatriote" à l'échelle de la ville (ou du village) ? [fellow-townsman]

Tags: traduction, anglais

Je cherche à traduire `a fellow-townsman` de l'anglais.

Une idée ?

Comment: Je ne vois déjà même pas de mot pour désigner un habitant d'une ville (à part "habitant" qui est général et pas spécifique à la ville)...

Comment: con-citadin (sonne un peu trop... con)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Je pense qu'il est possible d'utiliser le mot "concitoyen" dans ce cas :

> Citoyen(enne) du même État ou de la même ville qu'une autre personne.
>   C'est mon concitoyen, nous sommes concitoyens, mes chers concitoyens.
>   Synon. compatriote.Ne laissons jamais violer les droits d'un de nos
>   concitoyens (Erckmann-Chatrian, Histoire d'un paysan,t. 1, 1870, p.
>   418).− Messieurs, mes chers concitoyens, commença le premier magistrat
>   de Fenouille (Bernanos, Monsieur Ouine,1943, p. 1495):

Answer (score 4):

On peut utiliser *[pays/payse](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pays)* (2ème onglet) mais cela sonne un peu désuet :

> Région., fam. Personne originaire du même village, de la même région qu'une autre personne. Synon. compatriote.Quant à madame Correur, elle venait d'accepter le bras d'un lieutenant de dragons, un pays à elle, qui lui devait un peu son épaulette (Zola, E. Rougon, 1876, p.105).Maître Nicolas (...) lui confia qu'il était natif, comme elle, des Marches de Lorraine (...). Elle lui répondait avec confiance, comme payse à pays et amie à ami (A. France, J. d'Arc, t.2, 1908, p.243).

Comment: Désuet may be désirable when the English word is also old and unused :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak: Effectivement :)

Comment: A mes oreille ça sonne plutot étranger (beaucoup plus que le mot anglais...), mais c'est interressant. Merci!

Answer (score 1):

La traduction serait sans doute

> co-administré(s)

On peut aussi, s'il est connu, les nommer par leur [gentilé](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentil%C3%A9). Ex. *viennois*, *parisiens*...